# Can Flutter disable assertions in debug mode?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy

[image]

My Flutter app gets in trouble when using a package calling native code(swift).

It occurs only on iOS.

package: flutter_reactive_ble

swift method: PluginController.scanForDevices(name:args:completion:)

assert: assert(!central.isScanning)

[image: Xcode assertion]

I know that assertions are disabled in release mode, but want to know a way to disable assertion in debug mode if it is.

Your answer will be really helpful.

Comment: you can try run without debug

Comment: 'without debug' means release mode?

Comment: my bad, dont know about xcode but if you use VScode, you will find this option under `Run`

Comment: This is useful when only have the emulator (emulator only can run in debug mode). Any updates?